Asp.net core API and DevExpress Reporting
I am trying to use DevExpress reporting with the.net core web API, but I didn't find any references.
Is there any reference to using the.NET core web API with devExpress reporting??
or any video. I tried to search the documents but didn't find anything. 

Get started with DevExpress - ASP.NET Core Controls - Reporting and DevExpress - Reporting for Web - Reporting for ASP.NET Core topics. There you can find starting general information, links to tutorials, videos, etc.
